# Groovy - How to replace methods of existing java classes

Tags: grails, groovy

How do I replace methods of an existing java class ([GrailsDataBinder](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/GrailsDataBinder.html) in my case).
I read that method calls for java classes doesnt go through invokeMethod, and hence it doesn't work, but I think there would be some solution.

I just tried this

```
GrailsDataBinder.metaClass.static.createBinder = {Object target, String objectName ->   
  throw new RuntimeException() 
}
```

And this

```
GrailsDataBinder.class.metaClass.static.createBinder = {Object target, String 
  objectName -> throw new RuntimeException() 
}
```

But that did not seem to have replaced the method, as my closure isn't being invoked, but instead the original method executes.

**update**

I just found that the closure is being executed if I call the createBinder from the test class itself - so it works and method is replaced

```
void testDataBinder() {
    GrailsDataBinder.createBinder(null, null)
}
```

However When it is invoked from DataBindingUtils, it always executes original method (DataBindingUtils is also a java class)

Following is the code inside DataBindingUtils that invokes the method.

```
binder = GrailsDataBinder.createBinder(object, object.getClass().getName());
```

Note : There are some similar questions asked earlier, but none of them have worked for me.

Comment: Is the call on DataBindingUtils being called from Groovy? The Groovy runtime is required to pick up the metaclass changes. If you're integrating Groovy into Java and the call is from Java, then it won't see the patched changes.

Comment: Yes, the call to DataBindingUtils is made through BindDynamicMethod which inturn called from a groovy class. And I have tried calling the DataBindingUtils directly from a grails unit tests case too.

Answer (score 2):

This is disappointing once you see the power of Groovy.  However, as you already know, many of the cool metaclass etc. features available in Groovy simply don't work as you would like on Java classes.

If you are trying to override, stub or mock stuff on a Java class for unit testing etc., I advise looking into Spock, because it uses 'magic' that actually works on Java classes also.

If you are try to override methods for some other reason, you should try extending the Java class with a Groovy class or 'wrapping' the Java class with a Groovy class to gain the metaclass features you want when external classes call you classes methods.  Unfortunately this still won't allow you to intercept calls that the Java class makes to itself.